# Average of the observations within certain dates using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame( date = rep(c(1:10),5), obs = c(1:50) )
```

where in one columns I have dates and in the other column I have a variable `obs`. I would like to use `dplyr` to compute for each row the average value of the variable `obs` for the observation within 2 days of the value of `date`, excluding the current row of `date`.

For example for `date = 3` in row `13` I want to take all the rows with `date` equal to 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 and take the average of the value `obs` for these row, excluding the value of `obs` in row `13`. This would yield:

```
mean(c(1:5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 21:25, 31:35, 41:45))
# 23.41667
```

where you can see that I took all the observations for the dates between `1` and `5` but I left out the observation for row `13`.

Ideally, I would like to do it on any date: my dataset does not have contiguous dates or there could be multiple observation for the same day. So if the dataset looks like:

```
data <- data.frame( date = c(rep(c(1:10),5), 3), obs = c(1:51) )
```

where the date `3` is repeated twice, I would like to get the following mean for the observation in row `13`:

```
mean(c(1:5, 11, 12, 14, 15, 51, 21:25, 31:35, 41:45)) 
# 24.52
```

and the following mean for that in row `51`:

```
mean(c(1:5, 11:15, 21:25, 31:35, 41:45))
# 23
```

Basically, for each row I would like to have the mean of all the `other` observations in column `obs` happening within 2 days (+- 2 days) of the date in that specific row.

Comment: Will you provide expected results? Or will you explain your situation a bit more?

Comment: Agree with jazzurro. Context and expected outcome would be helpful.

Comment: I added a numerical example. I hope it is clear now. Please, let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Based on your second dataset, the logic is not clear to me.  Otherwise, it would be `lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(i) {x1 <- data$date[i]; x2 <- (x1 - 2): (x1 + 2); x3 <- x2[x2 >= min(data$date) & x2 <= max(data$date)]; x4 <- data$obs[data$date %in% x3]; mean(setdiff(x4, data$obs[i]))  })[[13]]
#[1] 23.41667`

Comment: I had a typo in the example: the variable `data` should have been `data <- data.frame( date = c(rep(c(1:10),5), 3), obs = c(1:51) )`. In this case the dates are not ordered, and your method works well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If we want to get the average for 4 values i.e. 2 values above, 2 below excluding the value, use a loop

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(i)
     mean(data$obs[pmax(0, setdiff((i-2):(i+2), i))], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or use `rollapply` with `partial = TRUE`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    mutate(avg = (rollapply(obs, width = 5, FUN = "sum", align = "center", 
        fill = NA, partial = TRUE) - obs)/rep(c(2:4, 3:2), c(1, 1, n()-4, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this answer the question. I added a numerical example. Please, let me know if it is still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

Solution 1 is calculating the mean from 2 rows below and 2 rows above of the actual date:

```
data %>%
  mutate(temp1 = lag(obs, 1), 
         temp2 = lag(obs, 2),
         temp3 = lead(obs, 1),
         temp4 = lead(obs, 2)) %>%
  mutate(mean = rowMeans(cbind(temp1,temp2, temp3, temp4), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(date, obs, mean)
```

Solution 2 is calculating the mean from 2 rows below and 2 rows above of the actual date, but considering all occurrences of a date:

```
data %>%
  mutate(temp1 = lag(obs, 1), 
         temp2 = lag(obs, 2),
         temp3 = lead(obs, 1),
         temp4 = lead(obs, 2)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(n = n(),
         mean = sum(temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, na.rm = TRUE)/(4*n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(date, obs, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this does not give the same result as in the example.